# How do I pull a Content Block into my email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, content-builder

How do I pull a Content Block into my email built in Classic Content? I tried using the below code:

```
%%=ContentBlockbyID("384201")=%%
```

But it won't populate in the Preview area.

Comment: Not sure why your question was flagged as unclear.  Seems pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use [**ContentArea()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentarea3/#ContentArea) or [**ContentAreaByName()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/contentareabyname4/#ContentAreaByName) in Classic Content.